# Spring boot 3 kotlin How mark field with default value as optional in swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.3.0` with spring boot 3
I do not have any custom config bean just using default
I have simple DTO class as following

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo1")
class DemoController{
    @GetMapping
    fun demoM1(@RequestParam(required = false) request: SomeRequest) : String = "demo"
}

data class SomeRequest(val name: String = "some name")
```

open-api json

```
"/demo1": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "demo-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "demoM1",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "request",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SomeRequest"
            }
          },

"SomeRequest": {
        "required": [
          "name"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
```

when I put this as request param of a controller the name field is showing as required in open api api-docs . Since name has default value my expectation is it will show as optional but it is showing as required.
How to make it optional?

Comment: Can you show your endpoint that you have ?

Comment: Post updated with endpoint please check

Comment: Why you are not passing this param as `@RequestParam(required=false)` instead of `@RequestBody` with single field ? And after it you will be able to handle optional param in swagger ui

Comment: I tried as you suggested. It still shows required true. Also as I mentioned in the question since there is a default value is there a way in the config or somewhere to mark them as optional

Comment: You have to change `@PostMapping` to `@GetMapping` and param to be `String` like it `@RequestParam(required = false) request: String` because it is an get endpoint in my opinion. If it not help you will be able to find more [Why my parameter is marked as required?](https://springdoc.org/#why-my-parameter-is-marked-as-required)